# How to make master detail relation (sub-report) in Birt designer with POJO data set?

Tags: java, birt, pojo

My birt report uses POJO data source. Here is my POJOs, getters and setters have been omitted for simplicity sake:

```
public class Author{
  String name;
  String email;
  List<Book> books;
}
public class Book{
  String title;
  String genre;
  Date publishDate;
}
```

My POJO data set is based on Author class. Now I want to make one table which will list all Authors and all his books. I've reviewed included to BIRT example report under the Sub Report folder. It does what I want but with JDBC data set. I can't figure out how to do the same but with POJO data set. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I am also having the same problem but grouping does not solve my problem as there are authors with the same name exist and also authors have to be listed in a particular sequence in the report. Any solution for this? kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar case is described [here](http://lifeinide.com/post/2014-12-25-birt-with-hibernate-using-pojos/). Your main class is Author class, but you can also add Book properties to data set columns. Then you will have the data set with all books that can be grouped by author name. Grouping can be done eg. in the list/table control configuration or in Data Cubes section.